# Can we add grafana custom panels via API?

Tags: python, grafana

The new set of requirments to add custom dashboard panels using python. Like I want to add once the new organization is onboarding, and automatically the visuals of specific org will be added.
I have read this docs https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation in the link you provided, it looks like to add a panel you would:

1. Get the dashboard by uid (`GET /api/dashboards/uid/:uid`)
2. Add a new entry to the `panels` list as suggested by the "Example Request for updating dashboard alert rule" example.
3. Update the dashboard via `POST /api/dashboards/db`